# Facebook API like a non-friend users post/photo

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

Is there a way to like posts, photos or similar of non-friend users(i.e normal facebook accounts)?

I have a like function using C# .NET Facebook API SDK which works great. I can like posts and so on. But the issue is that I cannot like posts from users that isn't a friend with the user who does the like.

I've played around a bit and made myself a Facebook page(like the ones companies use), I can like those posts, photos and so on without any issues.

But non-friend users is still a no-go. The error persists even if the post is set to public, I've tried to look around in the settings but I haven't found any settings that'll make it work.

Is it possible to like non-friend posts discounting public company pages?

Comment: Isn't there a difference between company pages and normal accounts?

Comment: @Noctis Yes there is a difference, company pages aren't accounts they're just pages that are being administrated by normal accounts. But in the end I'm just wondering whether you can like posts made by non-friends normal accounts. Or if it is limited to friends normal accounts and/or company pages.